# How to use sys.argv?

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, arguments

Hello I am trying to write a function which will take different argument and
would be used in another function in another script. My idea is to be able to precise a parameter directly from the terminal and the script will somewhat go the function with the precise parameter and Apply the correct line.

So I run my script like this and put f which is my parameter but I do not have any answer , below the full script.

```
C:\Users\Etu\ocuments>python test2.py f
```

first script

```
import sys

first_arg = sys.argv[1]

texte = "je MaNgE"

def get_command(texte, first_arg):
    if first_arg =="f":
        texte = texte.lower()
        return texte
    elif first_arg=="t":
        return texte.split()
    elif first_arg =="r":

    return texte

    else:
        raise Exception("Wrongfile feature type entered. Possible values: 't','f', 'r")
```

second script

```
from test import *


texte = "je MaNgE"

def choose (texte):
    texte=get_command(texte, first_arg)

    print(texte)
```

The idea is to modify directly the parameter from the shell without going Inside the script all the time.

Comment: Take a look at `sys.argv`or click which provide you tools handling your command line arguments.

Comment: for something simpler use `sys.argv`. For something more complex use standard modul [argparse](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) or one of the external modules like [click](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/)

Comment: I try but it is not working  can you help me debug the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need here is called **COMMAND LINE ARGUMENTS**.

here's a way to implement it.

```
import sys 
first_arg = sys.argv[1]
second_arg = sys.argv[2]
```

the *first_args* will hold whatever the first parameter is passed to the script and so on.

sys.argv is a list of parameters provided to the python interpreter. sys.argv[0] will always be the file name.

Answer (score 2):

## What you are trying to do can be easily achieved with the help of python command line arguments :>

*Consider the code that will help clear your understanding of command line arguments:*

```
"""
Filename: test.py
"""

import sys

def main():
    # always check to avoid IndexError
    if len(sys.argv) > 1:
        # sys.argv[0] always returns the current python file name

        print("Number of arguments: ", len(sys.argv))
        print("Filename: ", sys.argv[0])
        print("Hello", sys.argv[1])

main()
```

### **Note:
`sys.argv` returns**

> the list of command line arguments passed to a Python script. argv[0]
>   is the script name (it is operating system dependent whether this is a
>   full pathname or not). If the command was executed using the -c
>   command line option to the interpreter, argv[0] is set to the string
>   '-c'. If no script name was passed to the Python interpreter, argv[0]
>   is the empty string.

*Now when you run the above script using:*
`python test.py Lana`

*The output will be*

`Number of arguments: 2
 Filename: test.py
 Hello, Lana`

**Hope this will help you:)**

Comment: What else do you want to know?

Comment: thank you it works I have not call the function yet that's why